# How Do I Get Layered Navigation Filter using REST API

Tags: magento2, rest-api, layered-navigation

[image]

I used class as picture but it return wrong data
(attribute_code is correct but values wrong
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code and manage according to you like objectamanager.

```
 public function __construct()
   {
        $this->objectManager    = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
        $this->storeManager     = $this->objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');      
    } 


public function myFilteList()
{
    $storeId    = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $catgory_id = 12;


    $layer      = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category');
    $category   = $this->objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Category')->setStoreId($storeId)->load($catgory_id);
    if($category && $category->getId()) {
        $layer->setCurrentCategory($category); 
    }

    $min          = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMinPrice();
    $max          = $layer->getProductCollection()->getMaxPrice();      
    $filterprice  = ["min" => $min,"max" => $max];

    $attributes = $this->objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\FilterableAttributeList')->getList();
    $j          = 0;

    foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {

        $filterClassName     = 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute';
        if ($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
            $filterClassName = 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Price';
        } else if ($attribute->getBackendType() == 'decimal') {
            $filterClassName = 'Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Decimal';
        }            

        $filter     = $this->objectManager->create($filterClassName,  ['data' => ['attribute_model' => $attribute], 'layer' => $layer] );

        $attCode     = $attribute->getAttributeCode();
        $attlabel    = $attribute->getStoreLabel();
        $attOptions  = array();
        $filter_attr = array();
      
        foreach ($filter->getItems() as $option) {
            
            if($attribute->getAttributeCode() == 'price') {
                $attOptions[$j]['label'] = str_replace(array('<span class="price">','</span>'),'',$option->getLabel());
            } else {
                $attOptions[$j]['label'] = $option->getLabel();
            }
            $attOptions [$j]['values'] = $option->getValue();
            $j++;                
            $filter_attr = $attOptions;
        }

        if (count($attOptions) > 0) {                 
            $filterableAttributes [] = array ($attCode => array_values($attOptions) );
        }
           
        $filterlabel[] = array(
                    'att_code'     => $attCode,
                    'att_label'    => $attlabel,
                    'attr_options' => array_values($filter_attr)
                    );
        $attOptions = array();
    } // end foreach

    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($filterprice);
    print_r($filterlabel);
    echo '</pre>';
}
```